Can we use 'that' in a non-defining clauses?
Can we use "that" in a non-defining clause as in this sentence:

one should quit smoking, that is very harmful to health


Far better than that here would be it.

I agree, "it" is the best replacement. I would punctuate or rewrite: "One should quit smoking; it is very harmful to health." or "One should quit smoking because it is very harmful to health."

That is functioning as an ordinary demonstrative pronoun here, not introducing a relative clause.

in the sentence as written you should replace "that" with "which". If you add a full-stop after "smoking" the "That" is sort of ok, but "It" is better.

Multiple scholarly sources agree that it is always incorrect to use the relative pronoun "that" to introduce a non-defining (also called non-restrictive) relative clause.
The Purdue OWL advises:

"Whether to use that and which depends on whether the clause it introduces is restrictive or non-restrictive." ... "For a restrictive clause, use that."
... "Use which ... [in] a non-restrictive clause.
There is one other important distinction between restrictive and non-restrictive clauses: commas are used to separate the non-restrictive clauses from the rest of the sentence."

According to the Walden University online writing center,

'Although "that" is sometimes used in restrictive clauses, it is not allowed in nonrestrictive clauses.'

The Butte College website states the same distinction in less strict terms, saying that "generally" that is used for restrictive, and which for non-restrictive relative clauses.

If you visit any of the linked references, you'll also see many example sentences illustrating when to use each relative pronoun.

They also cover two additional important usage guidelines:

Non-defining/nonrestrictive relative clauses must be set off from the main clause by commas, while defining/restrictive relative clauses should not be set off with commas.
Some style guides prefer the relative pronoun who/whom over that when the antecedent is a person, but that is also acceptable for human antecedents. It is always incorrect to use which to refer to a person.


Note, though, that the word "that" as used in the example from your question can be grammatically valid if, as @StuartF suggests, you interpret it as functioning as a demonstrative instead of a relative pronoun!
